# QWebView on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, qtwebkit, qwebview

file pro:

```
QT       += core gui network webkit webkitwidgets
```

file widget.cpp:

```
#include <QtWebKitWidgets/QWebView>

QWebView * page_View = new QWebView(this);
page_View->resize(800,600);
page_View->load(QUrl("http://vk.com"));
page_View->show();
```

Errors:

:-1: error: cannot find -lxslt

:-1: error: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Have you installed xslt?

Comment: Install these deps and try to compile the project: https://github.com/IonicaBizau/johnnys-webview/blob/master/utils/deps.sh#L4-L14 I remember that I had problems like this.

Comment: @IonicăBizău: qtquick is not necessary here, nor location, nor declarative, nor sensors.

Comment: @LaszloPapp Possible, that's why I didn't add an answer. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to install the xslt library:

```
 sudo apt-get install libxslt1-dev libxslt1.1
```

If you still get further errors, you will probably miss out other dependencies, too, so you may need to install the webkit development package, too:

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5webkit5-dev
```

Provided that you are running a modern enough Ubuntu having this package available.

On a side note, you do not need add `core` and `gui` to the `QT` variable since they are added by default.